# Chef tabs get converted to spaces automatically

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am using a chef template which has tab spaces in it. When this gets converted into an actual file on the endpoint all the tabs are converted to spaces. This file is sensitive to spaces and tab to space conversion is no acceptable. Is there any way we can maintain the source template indentation on the endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

This isn’t something Chef implements, though we do normalize line endings on templates. Are you sure your editor isn’t doing it when you save the file?

Comment: Yes. My `.erb` file has correct indentation. Its when it gets created on the endpoint the tabs change to spaces.

Comment: You can look through the Erubis code but AFAIK https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/7910a42ca5999ae44c5b6b3dc256558b32b42481/lib/chef/mixin/template.rb#L177 is the only string manipulation we perform on template output.